# linear functional over real Banach space is bounded iff continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V$ be a real Banach space. So it comes with a complete norm. Prove a linear functional

$$f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

is bounded if and only if it is continuous.

I wanna say if bounded then continuous is the easy direction? a bit confused on this one.

Comment: Have you tried searching for a proof of this on the internet? Do you know the proof of the same statement where Banach Space is replaced with Hilbert Space?

Comment: I do not, is there a difference when swapping a Banach for Hilbert space?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded. Then $\forall x,y \in V$ one has

$$\vert \vert fx-fy \vert \vert = \vert \vert f(x-y) \vert \vert \leq M \vert \vert x - y \vert \vert.$$

Thus if we take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M}$ to show $f$ is continuous.

On the other hand suppose $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. Then by linearity of $f$, $f(0)=0$. If we choose $\epsilon = 1$ in the definition of continuity, then there exists $\delta >0$ such that

$$\vert \vert fx \vert \vert \leq 1$$

whenever $\vert \vert x \vert \vert \leq \delta.$

For any nonzero $x \in V$, define

$$\overline{x}=\frac{\delta x}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert}$$

Then $\vert \vert \overline{x} \vert \vert \leq \delta$ thus $\vert \vert f \overline{x} \vert \vert \leq 1$. Thus by linearity of $f$, we have

$$\vert \vert fx \vert \vert = \frac{\vert \vert x \vert \vert}{\delta} f \overline{x} \leq M \vert \vert x \vert \vert$$

where we can take $M=\frac{1}{\delta}$ and $\therefore$ $f$ is bounded.